# Proof Verification: Let $D=\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \} \cup\{0\} \subset \mathbb{E}^1$. Prove that $D$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $D=\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \} \cup\{0\} \subset \mathbb{E}^1$. Prove that $D$ is compact.

> *Proof*: It is clear that $D$ is bounded above by $1$ and bounded below by $0$. We need to show that the set $D$ is closed, or it
>   contains all of its limit points. The only limit point of the set $D$
>   is $0$. But since $D$ includes $0$, $D$ must be closed. Hence, $D$ is compact because it is closed and bounded.  $\blacksquare$

I claimed that $0$ is the only limit point of the set $D$ but is this okay? I stated it allegedly without giving much reasoning but I thought it was very obvious from looking at the set.

Can $D$ be its own open cover? If so, can I just give an example of finite subcover of $D$ to show that it is compact? For example, since $(2,0) \cup (0,2)$ covers $D$, $D$ is compact.

Comment: $D$ is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any open cover of $D$ must cover $0$. Let the basis containing $0$ in the open set containing $0$ be $(a,b)$, where $a<0$ and $b>0$.

By [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle), $\exists N \in \Bbb N:N > \dfrac1b$.

So, $\forall n \in \Bbb N: n > N \implies \dfrac1n \in (a,b)$ leaves finitely many elements of $D$ uncovered.

Pick, for each element uncovered, an open set containing that element.

It is clear that it is a finite subcover of $D$.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. But would my proof be also valid to be a proof? I think it's lacking some mathematical rigours but intuitionally makes sense to me.

Comment: @user3000482 I find no problem with your proof

Comment: Is your proof going to work for any closed set [a,b]?

Comment: @user3000482 I don't think so.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have hard time understanding your proof... can you explain in words so I can understand intuitionally what's going on here?

Comment: @user3000482 "compact" means that every open cover has a finite subcover. I'm showing an algorithm to construct the finite subcover.

Comment: So $(a,b)$ included with other intervals that cover $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n \leq N$ should be finite. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.